# how to count similar words in a column

Tags: php, csv

I have CSV file and would like to count repeated words in a column of 9000 row.

> exemple of the file 
>   thanks  
>   ok  
>   nice  
>   thanks  
>   nice  
>   thanks

the required result would be something like

> thanks=3, ok=1, nice=2 .

I found the following PHP code, but I couldn't get it to work, and copied the content of the CSV file into `file.txt` Am I doing something wrong?

```
<?php
$file = (''C:\Users\wnmb4793\Desktop\Test\file.txt'');

$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$tag = array();
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {

if (isset($tag[$col[2]])) {
$tag[$col[2]]++;
}
else {
$tag[$col[2]] = 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: To be honest, it might be easier just to import the csv into a database, then use SQL to show you all the words + how many occurrences.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code?

Comment: From your comment: `$value = $col[2]; // change 2 to column number you need` - evidently you need to select the right column. AndreyVolk has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few mistakes. Your code works.

```
$file = 'C:\Users\wnmb4793\Desktop\Test\file.txt';

$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');

$tag = array();
while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) 
{
  $value = $col[0]; // change 0 to column number you need, 0 - first 
  if ( isset($tag[$value]) ) 
    $tag[$value]++;
    else 
    $tag[$value] = 1;
}

print_r($tag);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [thanks] => 3
    [ok] => 1
    [nice] => 2
)
```

Comment: use $value = $col[0]; for the first column

Comment: in your case with a file of one column it should be $col[0] instead of $col[2]

Comment: With fgetcsv it does not matter. Use csv but do not forget to set $col[column number]

Comment: thanks for your help Andrey, i want to get the result not aligned but as column

Answer (score 1):

First problem I can see is:

```
 $file = (''C:\Users\wnmb4793\Desktop\Test\file.txt'');
```

Should be

```
 $file = ('C:\Users\wnmb4793\Desktop\Test\file.txt');
```

**The next step**

You need to loop through each word in the file. Something like:

```
while we are not at the end of the file.
     if( we have seen this word before ) // Think about the isset() method.
         find it's entry and add one to it's value
     else
         add a new entry, and set it's value to 1.
end while
```

I've given you the pseudo-code. Now turn it into PHP! :)

Comment: The original poster provided working code, he just missed a simple detail. Pseudocode is unhelpful here.

Comment: Agreed, but OP also mentioned that they had just copied and pasted. If OP ignores it, at least they can understand the methodology behind it, however that doesn't strictly answer the question, so you're right :)