# sort lines in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

i have this code that parse a csv file than gives me a chart, my problem is i want it to sort the lines of the csv file by alphabetic order than start comparing to find the same word and want it to stop an check the next word as soon as it doesn't find a similarity, so the program doesn't need to check 9000 * 9000 line .

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "uk-4_2_2013.complet.csv",
   dataType: "text",
   success: function(data) {processData(data);}
});
});

function processData(allText) {
// varriable qui contient toutes les lignes du fichier CSV
var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);

// liste des lignes 
var lignes=new Array(); 
var nombres=new Array(); 

// liste d'occurance qui correspond a chaque ligne
var nombre =[];
var x=0;
var y=0;
var inter1;
var inter2;
var i=0;
var j=0;    
//on parcours les lignes

for ( i=0; i<allTextLines.length; i++) 
  { 
    inetr1 = allTextLines[i].split(';');

      if(lignes.indexOf(inetr1[0])<0)
      {
             lignes[x]=inetr1[0];
             nombres[x]=0;
               for (j=0; j<allTextLines.length; j++)    
                {
                    inetr2 = allTextLines[j].split(';');
                   if (inetr1[0]==inetr2[0])
                     {
                       nombres[x]=nombres[x]+1;
                     }       
                }                   
         x=x+1;                                               
      }   
  }

 $('#Chart_App').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: lignes
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Apps Downloaded'
        }
    },
    series: [{

        data: nombres
    }]
});  
}
</script>

<div id="Chart_App">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

the csv look like this

```
house
home
world
house
home
```

thanks

Comment: sorting ~9000 lines in javascript and perform a search on them later on... You should _outsource_ it to some database ;)

Comment: ^ ..that you query using the same ajax on the server side. It will be faster, use less memory, and give a way better UX.

Comment: the code i posted works, the problem is the browser crashes for 40 sec when checking the csv file because of the loops to check the similarity but it sort them first it will save a lot of time .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952239/how-to-count-similar-words-in-a-column first comment in your post is going to be same as long as you keep using this method :D

Comment: You have literally just mentioned the exact point of outsourcing it to a database, as described in the first 2 comments.

Comment: thanks for you comment but that doesn't help me. i just need to add one or two lines to the code above that's all but i can't figure out how.

Comment: Put all the lines into an array, and use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @Ejay can't we just put them in variable ?

Comment: @h2ooooooo can you please show me how ?

Answer (score 0):

You already have an Array with your values in. You can just sort it like this:

```
var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
for(var i = allTextLines.length;--i;){
   allTextLines[i] = allTextLines[i].split(';');
}
//...
// now depending on your keys, sort your Array according to the
// index x where the relevant words are
allTextLines.sort(function(a,b){return (a[x] > b[x]);})
```

Now you have your Array `allTextLines` sorted and can do the rest of your stuff.

Comment: didn't work maybe i missed something !! i just copied your code .

Comment: `a` and `b` already are the array values, there are no two arrays built from the array `allTextLines` which could be accessed. Also what are you achieving by looping through the array and setting a `var inetr1`??

Comment: @Simon thanks for pointing out the typo:-p I think you could have figured out by yourself that it's a c&p error but who cares.

Comment: zazoo24, try again with this code. Replace `[x]` with the correct index (the index in the array where the names are stored).

Comment: Well the whole code didn't make any sense with that typo, that's why I didn't think it could be a typo right away, removed my down vote.

Comment: @Simon As I said, it was a c&p error - I took the line from OPs code and forgot to change `inetr2` into `allTextLines[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

As comments say, you should use a database to perform this operations with such big amount of data.

Anyway, in Javascript, once you have an array with the CSV values, you can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to sort it alphabetically.

```
allTextLines.sort();
```

This will change the original array.

EDIT: Counting occurences...

I understand you want to check how many occurrences of each word take place in the CSV. You have a CSV with one word per line, so allTextLines is an array with a word per element. After the sort() method, it is alphabetically ordered. This is an idea:

```
allTextLines.sort();

var lignes = new Array();  // diferent word values
var nombres = new Array();  // their occurrences
var word = allTextLines[0];  // temp word value
var count = 0;  // different words counter
var occurrence = 1; // occurrence of the temp word
for ( i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
  if (allTextLines[i] != word){
    lignes[count] = word;
    nombres[count] = occurrence;
    count++;
    word = allTextLines[i];
    occurrence = 0;
  } else {
    occurrence++;
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't know how, can anyone modify my code and post . as I'm straggling

Comment: Had no idea about the w3schools matter. Anyway, I never liked it.